# How can I export the frequency response from LTSPICE without phase wrapping?

Tags: ltspice, bode-plot, frequency-response, phase-margin

After I plotted the frequency response of a circuit using LTSpice as shown:

[image]

I exported the plots data as a .txt file in order to plot them after that using MATLAB, however, after I plotted the data using MATLAB I discovered that the exported data from LTSpice has the phase wrapped, as shown:

[image]

Is there a way to export the LTSpice frequency response without having the phase wrapped?

Comment: This is probably a choice made due to a requirement that \$\frac{-\pi}{2}\le\operatorname{atan}\left(\frac{Im}{Re}\right)\le\frac{\pi}{2}\$ when only the positive value from the \$\sqrt{Re^2+Im^2}\$ is always selected.

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot fix this in LTSpice.
I didn't find hard evidence, but very plausible evidence.
If you hover over the angle axis (you'll see a ruler) and left click it, there is an option to Unravel Branch Wrap. Why would the option here if there were no reason to unravel it?

[image]

If you deselect it, you'll see the same output as MATLAB shows.

So, I think you should unravel the data yourself, in MATLAB.

Comment: I'm no expert on MATLAB, therefore this in a comment: You could use something like ```wrapTo360(lon)-360``` or using modulo, or if (angle>0) subtract 360°

Comment: The unwrapping option is there to be applied to the already calculated data. Whether you check, or uncheck the option, the data doesn't change (the `.raw` file stays the same), which means that after exporting to Matlab, the option to wrap/unwrap is left to the user, the same way the option exists in LTspice. So the conclusion is correct: unwrapping must be done in Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

You can post process .raw files using Python and ltspice_pytool.
[PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/ltspice/)
[GitHub](https://github.com/DongHoonPark/ltspice_pytool)